# Can I know the value of a sum of elements if I know what the sum of their squares is?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say I know what the value of the following sum:

$$S_1^2 + S_2^2 + S_3^2 + S_4^2 + \cdots = \cdots T$$

Can I determine from this what the sum of the individual elements will be?

$$S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + S_4 + \dots = S$$

Comment: Even if they are all non-negative integers...$0^2+5^2=3^2+4^2$.

Comment: Consider a simpler example to see that this is impossible. Suppose we know that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Thus $(x,y)$ is a point on the unit circle. What can we say about $x+y$? Well, $x = \cos(\theta)$ and $y = \sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle of $(x,y)$ with respect to the $x$ axis. So $x+y = \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta)$. Plot this function to see that $x+y$ can be anything between $-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @lulu/Bungo. Why not just post answers?

Comment: @Aryabhata  Maybe it's a question about site policy.  Though people often protest, I don't like to post "answers" that are trivial computations (as here) or which are purely links.  That is, if I claim something as an answer I want there to be some actual content.  I can see where this question, for example, is a gray area...where the content is minimal but arguably non-zero.

Comment: @lulu: If the (trivial) comment fully answers the question as stated (in some reasonable interpretation), post a community wiki answer and if there are edits to be made, other folks can do it. There have been threads before in case you are interested: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments

Comment: @Aryabhata  Good suggestion, thanks.  Mind you, I have no idea how to post a community solution but I expect I can sort that out.

Comment: @lulu to post a CW question or answer, while you are still editing the post, look for the CW (community wiki) box and click that. My memory is that it should be at the lower right corner of the editing window.

Comment: @WillJagy  Thank you!  I was searching hither and yon for it.  It's seriously not obvious.  I have it now though, thanks again.

Comment: @lulu good. There are just a few times when this is useful. I use CW if I am posting an answer that I know is going to be unpopular. That way downvotes do not affect my reputation and I am not notified about them ( although, if people post nasty comments I still get notified of those). I am thinking of when people post Project Euler questions here and I notice, I have a letter from a PE moderator that I post as an answer. Another type is when someone else has posted a good answer but I feel some small point needs explanation, it seems good manners to use CW.

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot be.

Taking an example from the comments

$$ 0^2 + 5^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$$

Sums are 5 and 7.